# Replace a character string based on a separate list/dataframe R

Tags: r, replace, character, tidyverse, gsub

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be pretty simple that has me stumped.

Say I have the following data frame:

```
id <- c("bob_geldof", "billy_bragg", "melvin_smith")
code <- c("blah", "di", "blink")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,code))

> df
             id  code
1    bob_geldof  blah
2   billy_bragg    di
3  melvin_smith blink
```

And another like this:

```
ID1 <- c("bob_geldof", "melvin_smith")
ID2 <- c("the_builder", "kelvin")
alternates <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID1, ID2))

> alternates
            ID1         ID2
1    bob_geldof the_builder
2  melvin_smith      kelvin
```

If the character string in df$id matches alternates$ID1, I'd like to replace it with alternates$ID2. If it doesn't match I'd like to just leave it as it is.

The final df should look like

```
> df
               id   code
1 bob_the_builder   blah
2     billy_bragg     di
3   melvin_kelvin  blink
```

This is obviously a silly example and my real dataset requires lots of replacements.

I've included the 'code' column to demonstrate that I'm working with a data frame and not just a character vector.

I’ve been using gsub to replace them individually but it's time consuming and the list keeps changing.

I looked into str_replace but it seems you can only specify one replacement value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

EDIT: Not all ids contain underscores, and I need to retain the bit that does match. E.g. bob_geldolf becomes bob_the_builder.

EDIT 2(!): Thanks for your suggestions everyone. I've got round the problem by merging the data frames (so that there are NAs where there's no change to be made), and creating new IDs using an ifelse statement. It's a bit clunky but it works!

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `dataframes` use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` so as to not deal with factors. Then, if the rows are ordered, just apply:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,code),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
alternates <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID1, ID2),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$id[c(TRUE,FALSE)]=paste(gsub("(.*)(_.*)","\\1",df$id[c(TRUE,FALSE)]),
                         alternates$ID2,sep="_")

> df
               id  code
1 bob_the_builder  blah
2     billy_bragg    di
3   melvin_kelvin blink
```

If they are unordered, we can use `dlyr`:

```
df%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(id=if_else(length(which(alternates$ID1==id))>0,
                                  paste(gsub("(.*)(_.*)","\\1",id),
                                        alternates$ID2[which(alternates$ID1==id)],sep="_"),
                                  id))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  id              code 
  <chr>           <chr>
1 bob_the_builder blah 
2 billy_bragg     di   
3 melvin_kelvin   blink
```

We are using the same logic as before. Here we check the `df` by row. If its `id` matches any of `alternatives$ID1` (checked by `length()`), we update it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just trying to figure out what's going on in the gsub part.

What does this part do?: "(.*)(_.*)","\\1"

Also, you mentioned the rows being ordered. My real data frame is not in any particular order and contains thousands of rows, whereas the 'alternate' data frame only contains around 100. How should these be ordered?

Comment: Hello, in `gsub` we are telling the function to look for two patterns: `(.*)` grabs every character and `(_.*)` all characters after `_`. Whe then replace it by `\\1`, which means the first pattern we have matched (this way we discard the second part). This is then pasted with the `ID2` value via a `_`. Hope it is clearer now!

Comment: @SDes let me know if the new solution works for you :)

Comment: It's unclear if the formatting of the ID value with an underscore is consistent across all the data?  This may or may not be a reliable assumption?

Comment: @Soren , you're right, some of the IDs don't have underscores in them!

Comment: could you update your dummy variable to include cases which fail to work?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses base-R and is streamlined a bit.  Step 1: merge the main "df" and the "alternates" df together, using a left-join.  Step 2: check where there the ID2 value is not missing (NA) and then assign those values to "id".  This will keep your original id where available; and replace it with ID2 where those matching IDs are available

The solution:

```
combined <- merge(x=df,y=alternates,by.x="id",by.y="ID1",all.x=T)
combined$id[!is.na(combined$ID2)] <- combined$ID2[!is.na(combined$ID2)]
```

With full original data frame definitions (using stringsAsFactors=F):

```
id <- c("bob_geldof", "billy_bragg", "melvin_smith")
code <- c("blah", "di", "blink")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,code),stringsAsFactors = F)

ID1 <- c("bob_geldof", "melvin_smith")
ID2 <- c("the_builder", "kelvin")
alternates <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID1, ID2),stringsAsFactors = F)

combined <- merge(x=df,y=alternates,by.x="id",by.y="ID1",all.x=T)
combined$id[!is.na(combined$ID2)] <- combined$ID2[!is.na(combined$ID2)]
```

Results: (the full merge below, you can also do `combined[,c("id","code")]` for the streamlined results).  Here, the non-matching "billy_bragg" is kept; and the others are replaced with the matched ID

```
> combined
           id  code         ID2
1 billy_bragg    di        <NA>
2 the_builder  blah the_builder
3      kelvin blink      kelvin
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for looking at this! I only need the bit that doesn't match to be replaced. So bob_geldof becomes bob_the_builder, rather than just 'the_builder'. This works fine in a plain old gsub, but then I have to individually specify each replacement value.